# Why doesn't Android platform run desktop apps?

Tags: java, android, mobile, tablet

This might seem an obvious simple question but I need to understand because I am new to mobile programming world. My question is, for a program to be runnable on a mobile/tablet device why should it only be designed specifically for these devices? in other words, why doesn't Android 3.0 on Motorola Xoom permit running simple desktop Java program?

Thanks,

M.H.

Answer (score 5):

Because android really isn't using Java, per se. It's using Dalvik VM, which isn't the same as a Java VM.
Read more here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)